# Is it possible add more bounty on a question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I had start bounty my [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363622/a-program-made-in-c-runs-on-double-click-in-windows-but-not-in-linux) worth of 50 but is it possible to add more 50 right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not until the current one expires.

From the [Help Center > Reputation & Moderation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> - Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time.